# How to shorten length of auto generated password sent during registration?

Tags: password

is there a way to shorten the length of the 'auto generated password' which is sent during registration of a new user?

I would like to shorten this password to 5 characters max and also remove the numbers '0' and '1' as they can be confused for letters 'O' and 'L'.

My users are not very tech savvy and most don't know how to copy and paste a password. They type each character instead which can be time consuming and frustrating at the same time which is why I am looking to shorten the password.

My wordpress version is: 3.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `random_password` hook. It will trigger on new registrations once a random password has been generated.

```
add_filter('random_password', 'modify_the_pass');

function modify_the_pass($pass) {
    $pass = substr($pass, 0, 6); // make $pass six characters
    return $pass; // return our new $pass
}
```